# Is there an inherent difference in Tkinter grid column spacing on MacOS vs Windows? If so, how do I get around that?

Tags: python, tkinter, padding

I've been going through some tkinter video tutorials and documents, trying to get the hang of spacing things out with the grid layout in order to use it for my own applications, but when I try and use the grid spacing, it seems to add extra spacing/padding that I did not code in.

The more I look into this, the more it just seems like a MacOS vs Windows issue, but if that is the case, does anyone know a way around it?

For example, I tried just to copy and paste the code for the calculator found at this link: https://zetcode.com/tkinter/layout/, and I get two very different results.

The top image is the one from the example page, which looks like it was done on windows, while the bottom image is what happened when I copy/pasted the code and tried it out for myself.

[image]

[image]

This spacing isn't *that* bad, and if I have to deal with it, I guess I'll just do so, but when I was trying the code below from a video tutorial, my layout is wildly different in the spacing.

I have linked the video as well because at one point, the coder experiences some similar spacing, but then fixes it, and typing in the same code did not result in the same fix for me.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

e = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def button_click(number):
    #e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, number)

# Define Buttons

button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))
button_add = Button(root, text="+", padx=39, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_equal = Button(root, text="=", padx=98, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_clear = Button(root, text="clear", padx=88, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))

# Put the buttons on the Screen

button_1.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=2)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_add.grid(row=5, column=0)

button_equal.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2)
button_clear.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)


root.mainloop()
```

The first image is mine, the second is the coder's/YouTuber's. The spacing/padding between columns here just seems like way too much to just have "deal with" when building UIs. Does anyone have a workaround? I would like something that has the cleaner, more condensed look of the apparently-Windows layout/spacing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you know that `padx` values are in pixels? So it is display resolution dependent, which should've been explained by the youtuber.

Comment: Still trying these out. Found other issues with my python versions so I'm trying to sort that out as well.

Comment: Is that supposed to be part of an answer to this question? I do not think so

Comment: Sorry, it looked like I was responding to a comment asking to pick a correct answer.

Comment: Maybe you should accept something, the question askes about the difference, and both the values mention it. Its worth replying to them alteast for spending their time on your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use padx and pady = 0

`.grid(padx = 0,pady=0)`

This should reduce the spacing in between and it would look like the desired picture

Comment: This worked best! It closed up the space a lot with minimal alteration to the structure of my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`padx` and `pady` are dependant on the resolution of your screen (you should look up the methods for each widget), because the size is given in pixels.
You could maybe play with the placing, There are 3 methods to place your Buttons,Labels etc. in tkinter. `grid()`,`pack()`,`place()`. You should use the one that you feel comfortable with and fits your needs. You could maybe try something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title("Simple Calculator")

e = Entry(root, width=35, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def button_click(number):
    #e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, number)

# Define Buttons

button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_click(1))

#Place Buttons

button_1.place(relx=FLOAT,rely=FLOAT,relheight=FLOAT,relwidth=FLOAT)



root.mainloop()
```

`relx` and `rely` are
Horizontal and vertical offset as a float between 0.0 and 1.0, as a fraction of the height and width of the parent widget. So with place you have possibilities to adjust your widgets in relation to the main window.
(`relheight` and `relwidth` follow the same principle)
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm

Comment: _"same for almost everything in tkinter that has to do with sizing, height/width/x/y..."_ ~ Not entirely accurate. Buttons, labels, entries... takes in `width`/`height` which is not pixel.

Comment: @CoolCloud edited, you are right it depends what widget you are using. (Buttons for example : Width is the button width in letters (if displaying text) or pixels (if displaying an image))

Answer (score 0):

If the title is your question, then no, there is no major difference between Windows and macOS. But the sizing depends on the display resolution you are viewing on.

For example, the first image was done on a different resolution, so was the second. You should play around with `padx` and `pady` to make it fit to your resolution.

`padx` and `pady` will always be pixels by default and hence it will look different on different resolution(screen resolution is also pixels) based on the value.

The image when code is tried on a macOS big sur 11.3.1 1920x1080:

[image]

The image when code is tried on a macOS big sur but 1440x990 of [@roganjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799172/roganjosh):

[image]

As you can see, it is macOS itself, but the result is again different when you check the width of the buttons, fairly similar to what the youtuber got in Windows.

But furthermore you can see that the horizontal distance between the images also changes between the OS.